# Network Error: with Paperclip, S3 settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

**For development mode -  it uses local path:**
 url: "/system/documents/:id/:filename",
 path: "same to local path"

**for only production mode**, it checks the s3 storage: :s3,
s3_credentials:

it's working fine as long as I'm connected to internet, as I disconnect my wifi and start localhost, I'm getting following exception. when i connect back to internet, it worked fine and even pulled the files from local directory.

```
AWS::Core::Client::NetworkError: AWS::Core::Client::NetworkError
gems/aws-sdk-1.8.0/lib/aws/core/client.rb:318:in `return_or_raise'
```

any idea why in `localhost/development` mode or when wifi gets disconnect it check the s3 network ?